# JS getters: does defineProperty replace or complement the older, inline 'get' 'set' syntax?

Tags: javascript, properties, getter-setter, ecmascript-5, defineproperty

There seems to be an overlap in functionality between inline, object literal 'get function()' style and Object.defineProperty.

MDN docs for get https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get don't mention that inline 'get' functions are deprecated.

```
    var john = {
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName:  'Smith',
        age:        21,
        gender:     'Male'

        // () → String
        // Returns the full name of object.
        get name() {
            return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName
        },

        // (new_name:String) → undefined
        // Sets the name components of the object,
        // from a full name.
        set name(new_name) {
            var names = new_name.trim().split(/\s+/)
            this.firstName = names['0'] || ''
            this.lastName  = names['1'] || ''
        },
    }
```

This article from Mozilla's Jeff Walden in (what seems to be) 2010 stated:

*"We’ve removed support for a handful of obsolete getter/setter syntaxes in SpiderMonkey and Mozilla. This does not include { get property() { return "value"; }, set property(v) { } }, which is widely used and which is part of the latest standard."*

So:

- Is inline get/set OK?
- Is inline get/set deprecated in favor of defineProperty?
- When should I use each?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- inline get/set are OK
- they're not deprecated if favor of `defineProperty` (`__defineGetter__` and `__defineSetter__` are deprecated)
- `defineProperty` gives to you more granularity and control over the property you're going to define: you can decide if the property is `configurabile`, `writable` and `enumerable`. You can't do that with `get` and `set`. In addition, with `defineProperty` you could not define necessary a getter or a setter, but just a value.
- Use `get` and `set` when you do not need more granularity, it's a sugar syntax, and can be used in the object definition itself, where `defineProperty` has to be used once the instance is created. Use `defineProperty` when you need more granularity, or you do not need necessary to specify getter and setter but just a value.

Hope it helps.

*Links to the specs about `get` and `set`*

**ES5**: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5

**ES6 (draft)**: http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-method-definitions-static-semantics-propname

Comment: That's a super comprehensive answer, thanks! Can you provide a reference for 'get' still being in the current spec? I've been looking in the ES5 spec but it's somewhat hard to find....